# Angular datatable pagination not working or the search

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

For my table which binds from a web api, I was trying to using angular datatable baed on [this](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way)

So here is my component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { PortfolioEpicService } from 'src/app/shared/portfolio-epic.service';
import { PortfolioEpicModel } from 'src/app/shared/portfolio-epic/portfolio-epic.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-portfolio',
  templateUrl: './portfolio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./portfolio.component.css']
})
export class PortfolioComponent implements OnInit {
  pEpics:any;
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  constructor(private toastr:ToastrService,public service:PortfolioEpicService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 5,
      processing: true
    };
    this.refreshAllPortfolioEpics();
  }

}
```

So as expected the datatable is created (just binded). But there is no proper binding. I mean no pagination, no searching or none of the datatable functionalities are working.
[image]
What I did wrong ??

Comment: The sample you linked uses a Subject<any> as a trigger to inform the table to re-render. Your components typescript is not complete (at least `refreshAllPortfolioEpics` is missing), but do you use the trigger?

Comment: Thank you very much.. I missed that key point..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample you linked uses a `Subject<any>` as a trigger to inform the table to re-render.

Do that as well and it should work as expected.

Comment: @sandeep If my answer/comment helped you find the mistake. Please mark my answer as accepted.